# Why "Coronavirus" is written without space? shouldn't it be "Corona virus"?

Tags: compound-words

What is the rule for compound words in English? I know that this is pretty common in German but for English, I find it irregular in terms of the compound words.

Comment: Why do you think there is a 'rule'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning to write compound words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381672/learning-to-write-compound-words)

Answer (score 2):

> Names of viruses are often formed as single words with the suffix **-virus**. This is perhaps influenced by scientific use. There are rhinoviruses, noroviruses, adenovirus and so on. Again there isn't a logical rule, that is just how it is done. The virus that causes Ebola is known as ebolavirus (and note the downcasing when Ebola becomes a prefix) — [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/241779/coronavirus-why-no-c-capital-why-is-there-no-space)

Also, have a look at [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_classification) Wikipedia article, almost all the names of viruses are one word.

> For viruses that begin with a Greek letter, write it out and close up space between the letter and the rest of the word — [CDC web](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/page/scientific-nomenclature)
>
> Betaherpesvirus

**Edit:**
*Suffix -virus*:
Used to form taxonomic names of genera of viruses — [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-virus)